# How to get unslected item of dropdownbutton in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to set a reusable Widget (in a different file or library) that generates a DropDown between different objects that I get from Firebase. The way to invoke the widget is as follows:

```
CrearDrop(
 onChanged: (ObjetoModel? selectedObject) {
   _objeto = selectedObject!;
 },
 onSaved: (value) => _objeto = value
)
```

Within the main program the Widget loads the different objects from Firebase and allows me to select any of them, which allows me to conclude that onChanged is working correctly. The problem I'm having is that if the user doesn't select any object, I can't know which was the selected item (the first one in the list), since the function is in another file. Is there some callBack like onChanged that allows me to get that object without forcing a selection?

The reusable Widget that I have in a different file is the following:

```
class CrearDrop extends StatefulWidget {
  const CrearDrop({Key? key, required this.onChanged, required this.onSaved}) : super(key: key);

  final void Function(ObjetoModel?)? onChanged;
  final void Function(ObjetoModel?)? onSaved;

  @override
  State<CrearDrop> createState() => _CrearDropState();
}

class _CrearDropState extends State<CrearDrop> {


  ObjetoBloc objetoBloc         = ObjetoBloc();
  ObjetoModel? objeto           = ObjetoModel();

  @override
  void initState() {
    objetoBloc.cargarObjetosStream();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    objetoBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      
  return Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: objetoBloc.objetoStream,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ObjetoModel>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final lista = snapshot.data!;
                  objeto = lista[0];
                  return DropdownButtonFormField<ObjetoModel>(
                    value: objeto,
                    items: lista.map((ObjetoModel value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<ObjetoModel>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value.nombre!)
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  onChanged: widget.onChanged,
                  onSaved: widget.onSaved,
                  );
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              }
            )
    );
  }
}
```